# How to generate type forwarding assembly for whole assembly?

Tags: .net, sdk, proxy, command-line-interface

I have a situation where I want to generate a single DLL that contains type forwarding for a whole host of assemblies. The idea is to provide an SDK where a single DLL contains an 'empty proxy' for each type and method in the final product assemblies. My question is: is it possible to somehow generate these assemblies quickly? I mean, with all the correct types and interfaces?

Thanks.

Comment: You want type 'backwarding'.  Yuck.  That's a small convenience for your client that you'll pay for dearly.

Comment: @Hans care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`TypeForwardedToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.typeforwardedtoattribute.aspx) to forward a type from one assembly to another.

Now, to dynamically generate an assembly that forwards many types to another assembly, you can use `Reflection.Emit` or [`Mono.Cecil`](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil).

With these libraries, you can read your target assemblies for their public types, and generate an assembly that has a `TypeForwardedToAttribute` to each of those types.